# Save generated code in a special folder in "rtwbuild"

Tags: c++, matlab, save, code-generation

I am using `rtwbuild` to generated C++ code from a Simulation diagrams and would like to save generated code to an arbitrary directory. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control the folder for generated files in 3 different ways. You can set the "Code generation folder" option in Simulink Preferences. You can reach to Simulink preferences from any model using File menu and then choosing Simulink Preferences. This will change the code generation location for all models and will persist across MATLAB sesstions.

Second you can set a global param in MATLAB which will again control code generation directory for all models but will persist only for that MATLAB session. For example,

```
set_param(0, 'CodegenFolder', fullfile('C:','Work','mymodelrtw'))
get_param(0, 'CodegenFolder')
```

You can also use Simulink.fileGenControl object to set the codegen folder like the session param above. This object has more control about retaining previous folder paths and creating the folder optionally.

See the documentation for these at http://www.mathworks.com/help/rtw/ug/control-the-location-for-generated-files.html

Comment: Those are the main settings, but there are a couple of other options which might influence where your generated code lands. In the "Configuration Parameters" GUI, under "Code Generation -> Interface" you can set "Shared code placement" to "Auto" or "Shared Location". Under "Code Generation -> Code Placement" you can set "File Packaging Format" to "Modular" or "Compact". (R2015a)

Answer (score 0):

The generated code should be by default be in the a folder with the name of your model with some extension "_grt_rtw" or something else.
So you are supoosed to know the default output folder. By using the following commands, you will be able to move or copy your files:`movefile()  copyfile()`