# Check which Toolbox is used for generating C++ code

Tags: matlab

TO generate/build c++ code from Simulink diagrams one could use Embedded/Simulink Coder toolbox to generate C++ code from the give diagrams. Depending on which toolbox is used, generated code will be saved in a folder including part of `"System target file"` which is `grt.tlc` for Simulink Coder and `ert.tlc` for Embedded Coder Toolbox.

My question: is there any way to write a command to know which `"System target file"` is applied for the simulation's configuration?

In my code I need to know which target file is set up for deciding which method comes next?

Comment: Not sure what you want. Do you want to read the target from a opened model or from a folder of generated code?

Comment: Because Simulink Coder generates a folder including `_grt` and Embedded Coder generated a folder including `_ert` then I just want to know the type of target file and then will move the whole generated folder to another derive to run the next step. Because for each example the target file differs then I have to know it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the "System target file" using

```
get_param(gcs, 'SystemTargetFile')
```

You can also change build directory several ways. See the answer [Save generated code in a special folder in "rtwbuild"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31801383/save-generated-code-in-a-special-folder-in-rtwbuild/31812496#31812496) which explains ways of changing code generation directory. This changes only the top level directory. You will still see _grt or _ert directory inside this. But you can create a new directory before a call to rtwbuild and then you will have only one set of code generation files inside that.

Comment: great answer! exactly what I was looking for!